# Writing pom.xml for Android big project - cannot find symbol

Tags: android, maven

our team decided to use Maven in our pretty big project (300 classes) and I'm new at it. So far I am writing pom.xml file. I wrote all libraries into `<dependency>`, but don't know what to do next. My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.asd.android.asd</groupId>
<artifactId>asd</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>asd</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-no_aop</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>r7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>20030203.000550</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.roboguice</groupId>
        <artifactId>roboguice</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
        <artifactId>signpost-commonshttp4</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
        <artifactId>signpost-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.11</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.asd.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

</build>
```

And for every class I get such an error :

```
  [ERROR]  interface AccountService
/Users/asd/Documents/asd/asd-android/asd/src/com/asd/android/asd/api/ws/AccountService.java:[46,25] error: cannot find symbol
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Can have many reasons, you should check in the `AccountService` for which symbol is unknown. If your are using Eclipse, there should be a marker in the console window indicating the position of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The POM looks incomplete to me, the android-archetype POM also configures the android-maven-plugin, specifying both a SDK element and a Emulator element. Have a peek here,

https://github.com/akquinet/android-archetypes/blob/master/android-quickstart/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml

If its the first time you are doing a android project, and you have a massive mammonth of a project, I would suggest that you use the archetype to build a new mavenized project, ensure the "Hello world" type project included with the archetype runs.

Then, one you are happy that works in your IDE and from the console, then you copy over your main project and refactor the archetype to fit your project.

Comment: Yep, its incomplete, but didn't know what to add. I have already testes small projects and it all works. So now I have to challenge myself with this mammonth hah. Thanks for link, will check it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you didn't mavenized your Eclipse project after inserting your pom.

Right click on project base ->  Configure -> Convert to Maven project

**Edit**

Other possible causes:

1) You didn't put your srources in

- src/main/java
- src/test/java

2) Some fields are missing or incomplete in your pom:

```
<packaging>apk</packaging>
```

in header:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.asd.android.asd</groupId>
<artifactId>asd</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>asd</name>
```

build:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <sdk>
            <!-- platform or api level (api level 4 = platform 1.6) -->
            <!-- platform or api level (api level 8 = platform 2.2) -->
            <!-- platform or api level (api level 16 = platform 4.1) -->
            <!-- platform or api level (api level 17 = platform 4.2) -->
            <platform>16</platform>
          </sdk>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: I have done that previously + now I did update, still doesn't work